# How to create new entry in std::map without copying the entry value - no pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdmap

I have a map:

```
std::map<std::string, MyDataContainer>
```

The `MyDataContainer` is some `class` or `struct` (doesn't matter). Now I want to create a new data container. Let's say I wanna do it with default constructor available:

```
// This is valid, MyDataContainer doesn't need constructor arguments
MyDataConstructor example;
// The map definition
std::map<std::string, MyDataContainer> map;
std::string name("entry");
// This copies value of `example`
map[name] = example;
// Below, I want to create entry without copy:
std::string name2 = "nocopy"
// This is pseudo-syntax
map.createEmptyEntry(name2);
```

Is there way to do that? To skip creating helper variable when I just wanna initialize it in map? And would it be possible to do it with constructor arguments?

I think this question also applies to other std containers, like [stdvector](/questions/tagged/stdvector) or [stdlist](/questions/tagged/stdlist).

Comment: [std::map::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) Perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `emplace`:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

std::map<std::string, X> m;

m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple("nocopy"),
          std::forward_as_tuple());
```

This generalizes to arbitrary consructor arguments for the new key value and mapped value, which you just stick into the respective `forward_as_tuple` calls.

In C++17 this is a bit easier:

```
m.try_emplace("nocopy"  /* mapped-value args here */);
```

Comment: Is there any danger related to it? I don't remember ever seeing this in use, that's why I'm curious. In docs, it starts "*Careful use of emplace allows...*". Why careful?

Comment: @TomášZato: The danger is that you forget how to spell this, and that every one of your readers will say WAT?

Comment: What readers? Wouldn't compiler simply throw error upon typo?

Comment: @TomášZato: I'm assuming that code is written primarily for humans. It goes without saying that your code compiles, but the real difficulty is whether anyone will use this code in the future when you're gone...

Comment: @TomášZato: The difference between "insertion" and "emplacement" semantics is that emplacement uses explicit constructors, so you have to be careful about conversions. E.g. `m.insert(std::chrono::seconds(1))` works and `m.insert(10)` does not, but `m.emplace(10)` does. So when you emplace you generally need to be aware of the types, moreso than when you insert.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `map::emplace`: see [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(42), // argument of key constructor
          std::forward_as_tuple());  // argument of value constructor
```